# how BigInteger method bitLength() returns 2 when applied on BigInteger "-4"?

Tags: biginteger, java

```
BigInteger n1= new BigInteger("-4");
System.out.println(n1.bitLength());
```

**How it returns bit length 2? Please explain.**

Comment: From the javadoc: *Computes (ceil(log2(this < 0 ? -this : this+1))*, for `-4` it returns `2`.

Comment: Why do *you* expect anything else? You can easily check that this is correct if you follow the docs, what confuses you?

Answer (score 0):

The bitLength method of BigInteger class is used to return the number of bits in the minimal two’s-complement representation of this BigInteger, excluding a sign bit.

The minimal two's complement representation of -4 is "100", by excluding the sign bit we get "00" which is 2 bit long. So it returns 2.